# iPhone motherboard transplant

Tags: iphone, motherboard

I am in a bit of a pinch, as I just broke the digitizer ribbon cable when I was replacing the glass/LCD of a Sprint iPhone 4.

I have a lot of iPhone 4's laying around, and I was wondering if I can replace the mother board. If I were to take the motherboard off of the phone that I broke the digitizer to, and installed it in another Sprint iPhone 4, would there be any issues?

My main concern is connecting to the cellular network and the persons data. Both of which is stored on the mother board, correct? (At least on a non AT&T iPhone 4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be yes. You can safely transplant the motherboard of a Sprint iPhone 4.

After about 30 seconds from turning the device back on, it will connect to the service provider, and resume normal operations.

Comment: So did the MEID change or anything need to be done to resume service once you had exchanged the logic board from one device into the shell/battery/screen of another?

Comment: After about 30 seconds of turning the phone back on, it connected to the network and began loading texts. I do not know how to check the MEID, but because it connected, does that mean it was the same?